# ES6 arrow functions trigger "'super' outside of function or class" error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider the following super class and sub class extending it:

```
class SuperClass {
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    sayName = () => {
        alert(this.name);
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    constructor(name){
        super(name);
    }

    sayName = () => {
        super.sayName();
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = this.name;
    }
}

let B = new SubClass('Noam Chomsky');
B.sayName();
```

In this example the function `sayName` is written as an arrow function in both class definitions. And when I call `B.sayName()` I get an error saying:

> 'super' outside of function or class

[JSFiddle demonstrating the error](https://jsfiddle.net/s4auw322/1/) (Check the console)

---

However, if I re-write the class definitions to not use arrow functions, everything works fine and I do not get an error:

```
class SuperClass {
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    sayName() {
        alert(this.name);
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    constructor(name){
        super(name);
    }

    sayName() {
        super.sayName();
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = this.name;
    }
}

let B = new SubClass('Noam Chomsky');
B.sayName();
```

[JSFiddle demonstrating that it works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/s4auw322/2/)

Can someone explain why I'm getting this error when I use arrow functions here?

Comment: why do you want to define `sayName` as an arrow function in the first place? `sayName = () => {
        alert(this.name);
    }` syntax is not even standard yet (it's currently stage 2)

Comment: There might be an issue with the Babel version jsfiddle is using. As one of the answers said, calling `super.sayName()` wouldn't work anyway because there is no `sayName` method on `SuperClass.prototype`. **However**, referencing `super` inside the SubClass' `sayName` method should work. After all, the code is the same as (note that I made `sayName` a proper method in `SuperClass`): https://jsfiddle.net/5y9bqwd0/

Comment: And here is another option for child arrow function property: https://jsfiddle.net/zoeh5bp2/. Bot of them are about closuring `super` from constructor.

Comment: @FelixKling An earlier answer to this question referenced this bug report for Babel: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/3930#issuecomment-245408381, explaining that the issue is linked to generators not being able to call super.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that

```
sayName1 = () => {
    alert(this.name);
}
```

is a property with function type, while

```
sayName2() {
    alert(this.name);
}
```

is a method. And ES classes handle methods and properties in entirely different ways. Methods are existed on class prototype, while properties are being assigned to every instance. And you can't access parent's `sayName1` via `super.sayName1` due to it is not on your parent's class, it is only on instance object and could be accessed via `instance.sayName1`.

Also, from [ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> An ArrowFunction does not define local bindings for arguments, super,
>   this, or new.target. Any reference to arguments, super, this, or
>   new.target within an ArrowFunction must resolve to a binding in a
>   lexically enclosing environment... An ArrowFunction that references
>   super is always contained within a non-ArrowFunction and the necessary
>   state to implement super is accessible via the scope that is captured
>   by the function object of the ArrowFunction.

Comment: *"you can't access parent's `sayName1` via `super.sayName1` due to it is not on your parent's class"* That's correct, but that would result in a different error. It seems the OP cannot even reference `super` inside the arrow function, but it should work IMO, since it's just syntactic sugar for assigning the function inside the constructor.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer because it explains why one shouldn't use arrow functions here, even though my specific error looks to be caused by a bug in Babel (see my comment above).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, arrow functions act just like regular functions in most instances.  However, when you are dealing with instances where the "this" keyword would come into play, the arrow function binds "this" to the context where it was defined.  If you use a regular function you should have no problems.

Comment: Try console.log(this); in both the superClass and subClass and you will see what I mean

Comment: What does this have to do with the OP's problem?